# How do I make play framework (1.3.1) module unit test classes appear in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a few play framework 1.3.1 modules that are used in other play 1.3.1 applications. I want to start writing unit tests to these modules.

I have tried creating a "test" folder (which contains some test cases) in the modules and re-importing the main application in eclipse. I do not see the module test folder anywhere.

How can I make this work so that I can easily edit the test cases within eclipse?